Why is this prove for $\mathbb{P}_{z_0}(T(D)<\infty)=1$ true?
I have the following statement:

Let $D\subsetneq \mathbb{C}$ be a simply connected domain and $z_0\in D$. Let $B$ be a complex brownain motion with $B_0=z_0$. Then, $\mathbb{P}_{z_0}(T(D)<\infty)=1$ where we defined $T(D)=\inf\{t\geq 0: B_t\notin D\}$.

I have the following proof which I do not completely understand:
Since $D\subset \mathbb{C}$ is a simply connected, strict subset, by the Riemann Mapping Theorem there exists a conformal isomorphism $\phi:D\rightarrow \mathbb{D}$. By the conformal invariance theorem we already know that $\left(\phi\left(B_{\sigma(t)}\right)\right)_{0\leq t<T(\phi(D))}=\left(\phi\left(B_{\sigma(t)}\right)\right)_{0\leq t<T(\mathbb{D})}$ is a complex Brownian motion under $\mathbb{P}_{\phi(z_0)}$. Hence, as $t\uparrow T(\mathbb{D})$, eventually $|\phi(B_{\sigma(t)})|\geq \frac{1}{2}$. But $B$ is neighbourhood recurrent, which means that a.s. $B$ intersects the open set $\left\{z\in D: |\phi(z)|<\frac{1}{2}\right\}$ infinitely often. Therefore, a.s. $B$ exits $D$ in finite time, i.e. $\mathbb{P}_{z_0}\left(T(D)<\infty\right)=1$.
I don't see why the last sentence follows, i.e. why we can conclude that $\mathbb{P}_{z_0}\left(T(D)<\infty\right)=1$, can someone explain this to me?
